# "Should" WebDriver proxy bypass 0.0.0.0:00?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver, http-proxy

I have configured Python Webdriver to use a proxy with Firefox using the standard configuration as outlined [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy), with 0.0.0.0:00 as the host and port.

```
myProxy = "0.0.0.0:00"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })
driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

When I then request a webpage and view the HTTP traffic, I see the request and response bypassing the proxy and going straight to the page. Should this be the case? And if so, why? (I know Python and WebDriver, I know very little about proxies.)